# Click dummy rails 'submit' button that does final checks before posting

Tags: javascript, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, braintree

I'm currently upgrading our Braintree SDK which uses JavaScript to hijack the Rails form 'submit' button, makes a call to Braintree.js, and on success, allows us to Post our data as normal.

The issue is that we are already piggybacking on the submit button, checking form data with a few JavaScript methods, then calling `$form.submit()` to continue Posting the data. The two are conflicting.

My solution is to create a fake "submit" button and on click, have it run the methods to verify data, THEN have it call `$form.submit()`, allowing Braintree.js to hijack the real submit button. Am I not correctly invoking the submit call on the form?

My fake submit button followed by the actual submit button (with id: place_order_submit)...

```
%p.advance-container.clearfix
    %input#check-order.btn.btn-xlarge.btn-primary.action-check-order{type: 'button', value: 'Check Order'}
    %input#place_order.btn.btn-xlarge.btn-primary.action-submit{type: 'submit', id: 'submit', value: 'Place Order'}
```

This is the Coffeescript that should do its thing (i.e. double check the order) then "click" the submit form button to have it process/post as normal (allowing it to be hijacked by Braintree).

```
$form: $('form')
$formGroups: $(".form-group")
formGroupIds: $('.form-group').map -> $(this).attr('id')
lastFormGroupId: $(".form-group").last().attr('id')
$checkOrderButton: $('#check-order')

@$checkOrderButton.on 'click', (event)=>
    event.preventDefault()
    try
      q.Orders.items.isAssertAllAvailablePollEnabled = false
      @$pageCover.show()
      $.when(@items.ensureAllAvailable(), @shippingAddr.save(), @billingAddr.save())
      .done =>
        q.Logger.debug 'pre-Braintree requests done, go!'
        q.Util.resetSubmissionState 'form'
        @$checkOrderButton.off('click')
        $('#place_order_submit').submit() # <-- THIS ISN'T WORKING
      .fail ->
        q.Orders.items.isAssertAllAvailablePollEnabled = true
        q.Logger.warn "At least one pre-Braintree request failed, submit halted. Details: #{JSON.stringify(this, null, 4)}"
        q.Util.resetSubmissionState 'form'
        @$pageCover.hide()
    catch ex
      q.Logger.warn "pre-Braintree request failed with exception: #{ex}"
      q.Util.resetSubmissionState 'form'
      @$pageCover.hide()
```

Comment: Can you share which Braintree integration you are using (custom, drop-in, etc?) and maybe provide your `braintree.setup` code?

Comment: Thanks @kdetella. I realized my mistake and thought I posted the answer below, but I guess not. All I had to do was change this line...
     $('#place_order_submit').submit() 
to
    $('#place_order_submit').click()

Thank you though! :)

Comment: @kdub You can always post your own answer and mark it as accepted. That way people can see you found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my mistake...all I had to do was change this line...

`$('#place_order_submit').submit() to $('#place_order_submit').click()`

(Thanks @agf for the suggestion.)